# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\demo.php on line 27

Tags: php

When I am writing this code, I am getting a fatal error stating:

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\demo.php on line 27.

How can I get rid of this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$searchtype  = $_POST["searchtype"];
$searchterm  = $_POST["searchterm"];
$searchterm  = trim($searchterm);

if(!$searchtype && !$searchterm) {
    echo "You have not entered search details.";
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","books"); 

if($mysqli = false) {
    echo "ERROR:Sorry,Could Not Connect To The Database.";
} else {
    echo "Connected To Database";
} 

$sql = "SELECT author FROM books"; 

if($mysqli -> query($sql)) {
    echo "Connected To Tables";
} else {
     echo "Cannot connect tot tables right now."; 
} 


?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($mysqli = false)
```

This line is assigning the boolean value `false` to `$mysqli`. Change it to:
`if ($mysqli == false)`
or (better yet) `if ($mysqli === false)`.

To prevent this error in the future, I recommend you employ [Yoda conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). In other words:

```
if (false === $mysqli)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Also the query execution need to change to

```
if($mysqli->query($sql)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you check

```
if($mysqli = false)
```

when what you want is

```
if($mysqli == false)
```

However, this will not work if there is a connection problem as you will still get a mysqli instance back. You're looking for

```
if($mysqli->connect_error)
```

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) for more info